# How to write in two fields at a time in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, formula

I have two `UITextFields` one field is RISK and other is WIN. Now when user start writing in RISK field then it should accordingly calculate the value of WIN and should be filled in WIN field. Formula is this

```
    if (a<0) {
        WIN = RISK/(-a/100)

    }
    else {
                    WIN = RISK*(a/100)
    }
```

and if value is entered in WIN then it should populate the value in RISK, formula is
if (a<0) {

```
        RISK = WIN*(-a/100)
    }
    else {
        RISK= WIN*(100/a)

    }
```

so please guys guide me how can i populate the fields without pressing any button and how can i calculate the values?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a property for each field:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField win;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField risk;
```

and `IBAction` methods:

```
- (IBAction) winDidChange: (id) sender;
- (IBAction) riskDidChange: (id) sender;
```

Hook these up in interface builder to the **Editing Changed** event:

[image]

Your method will look something like:

```
- (IBAction) winDidChange: (id) sender
{
   float winValue = [self.win.text floatValue];
   float riskValue = <your calculation here>
   self.risk.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", riskValue];

}
```

.. and similarly for `riskDidChange:`

If you hook up the **Editing Changed** event of the `win` field to the `winDidChange:` `IBAction` in interface builder (and the same for `risk`), the method will be called every time a character is typed into the field.

You should read **The Target-Action Mechanism** section in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: but when i have to call these actions?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give more information

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the UITextFieldDelegate.  Set a class, perhaps your view controller to the delegate of the WIN textfield, then implement this method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Inside the method, convert the string to a number, run your formula, change the value of the RISK textfield and return YES.

Comment: This is the wrong method to use, as it gives the contents of the text field before the next character is typed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the delegate method ([UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate)) to make use of the following methods....

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
- textFieldDidBeginEditing:
- textFieldShouldEndEditing:
- textfieldDidEndEditing:
- textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

When a value changes, you can use these delegate methods to update your other value.

Comment: whenever these methods will be called?

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is

```
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and then

```
 - (void)myFunction:(id)sender {

     //calculate and show in WIN field

 }
```